# Can a component itself be used as a listener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener

I have tried using this code in Java, where I used a JFrame as it's own ActionListener. Now, it is theoretically possible, because in Java, a class can both implement a number of interfaces **and** extend another class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/*
 * This is an example of the strangeness of the syntax of Java. In this example, I am using the JFrame itself as the listener for its component, namely a JButton which, on clicking, ends the program. 
 * Warning : This is just an example, and I would never recommend this syntax, for I do not know the full consequences yet.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial") public class ListenerTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private final JPanel contentPane;
    private final JLabel message;
    private final JButton button;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                try{
                    ListenerTest frame = new ListenerTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ListenerTest(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 200, 150);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        message = new JLabel("Hello World");
        message.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        message.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(message, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Click Me!");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well, I listened for myself!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

My question is : Is there any problem in using a component as its own listener?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and works as expected. Some of the GUI generation tools can be configured to emit just the type of code. It might not be the best architectural pattern though, but sometimes useful (debugging , throw-away dialogs, custom widgets).

Comment: Does this technique have any problems? I saw that the GUI took a long time to load.

Comment: I only see it as a potential maintenance nightmare, but that's all. I'm not aware why or if at all should it slow the loading time.

Comment: OTOH it's a very useful technique for SSCCE's, when every irrelevant construct obscures what's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work ... yes.

That being said. I can give you hundred of examples of bad coding practices, and this would be one of them.

- There is almost never a need to extend the `Jxxx` classes in Swing (except perhaps for custom painting). In your example you can use a `JFrame` instead of extending it
- Having a class which implements the `ActionListener` interface suggests to users of your API/code that it can be used as an `ActionListener`. However, your class is not designed as an `ActionListener`. The fact that it is one is an implementation detail which can better be hidden. So use an `ActionListener` (anonymous class, inner class, ... ) instead of implementing it directly (or even better, use an `Action`)

And no, implementing the `ActionListener` interface directly has nothing to do with *I saw that the GUI took a long time to load*

And as a side-note. Better to use `JFrame#pack()` then the call to `setBounds`.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to implement the `ActionListener` on the class if it is used for a single button only?

The side effects of this are:

- adds to the fact other classes and components have access to this listener
- more checking will be needed to identify which component is firing the listener (as I see many reuse listeners for other components using if checks for which fired the listener).
- Not really good practice to implement a `Listener` on the class unless class will be used as a listener.

Proper solution IMO:

[Use anonymous inner class listeners:](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/events/anonymous_listener.html)

```
ActionListener al=new ActionListener() {
    @Override
     public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     }
};
```

now you can add this to your single button via `addActionListener`.

the reason I come to the above conclusion of not wanting to implement the listener on the class is in Swing You should not extend the `JFrame` class unnecessarily.

notes (not as relevant to particular problem):

- As my own coding preferecnce do not use `EventQueue` rather [`SwingUtilities.invokeXXX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) though as @Robin said who stated the docs: *As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()`*

Comment: Wondering ... why the advice for the `SwingUtilities` iso `EventQueue`. Looking at the implementation of `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` it just delegates to the `EventQueue` class. And the javadoc even mentions that: "As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for <code>java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()</code>"

Comment: @Robin hmmm well looking at the import statement isn't very Swing like: `java.awt.EventQueue` (maybe not necessary to not use it but all oracle tutorials show its use vs `EventQueue`)